# Apple Script: Resize and position Virtual Keyboard / KeyboardViewer

Tags: macos, scripting, keyboard, applescript

**If these are too many questions in 1, please tell me it and I edit the question and split it into 3? question.**

I am currently writing some apple scripts and tried some things with it.

I want to:

- open virtual keyboard (keyboardViewer)
- resize it
- position it
- deactivate controls like `close` `restore` and `minimize`

My scripts are these:

App 1:

```
tell application "System Events"
if not (exists (process "KeyboardViewer")) then
    do shell script "/usr/bin/keyboardViewer"
end if
end tell
```

App 2:

```
tell application "System Events"
if exists (process "KeyboardViewer") then
    click (process "KeyboardViewer"'s window 1's buttons whose subrole is "AXCloseButton")
end if
end tell
```

I am using the keyboardViewer by https://github.com/nriley/keyboardViewer in `/usr/bin/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I can not script my application. Resizing and positioning works with some applications but not with this one. Also hiding the controls on the top left of the window in mac os x is not possible.